# insertSegmentWith interger value in sorted

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I `insertSegmentWith` integer value to existing `uisegmentedcontrol`

```
[self.segmentAdd insertSegmentWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",t] atIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

It adding all giving value at index:0

But I want adding that numbers in ascending order (sorted in  ascending order)

Comment: How you insert the value in loop ? Where those values stored ?

Comment: buy giving value in text-filed it should be add to the segment with given   text-filed as segment title....